# XSL: how to split elements having a given sub-element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML like this

```
<a>
  <b attr = 'foo'>
    <d>text</d>
    <x attr1 = 'foo1'>x-text-1</x>
    <x>x-text-2</x>
    <e attr2 = 'foo2' />
  </b>
</a>
```

I need to split the entire tree rooted at `<a>` into two (or more) trees, having the same structure, but only one `<x>` per duplicate:

```
<a>
  <b attr = 'foo'>
    <d>text</d>
    <x attr1 = 'foo1'>x-text-1</x>
    <e attr2 = 'foo2' />
  </b>
</a>

<a>
  <b attr = 'foo'>
    <d>text</d>
    <x>x-text-2</x>
    <e attr2 = 'foo2' />
  </b>
</a>
```

The two new `<a>` nodes will be contained in another parent node. Apart from the presence of `a/b/x` paths, I don't know anything else about the structure (i.e., `<a>` or any other node, including `<x>`, might contain nodes I don't know of and all nodes might have attributes I don't know of).

I've tried to figure out how to do that in XSL, but I don't really have a concrete idea. I can only think of a for-each over all `a/b/x` and then a copy-of that starts from `a/` and excludes the `x` not equal to the one being considered by the current for-each iteration. But it's just an headache for me to try to code the idea in XSL, any help appreciated.

Comment: What defines a "duplicate"?

Comment: Why does the first split result have two `x` elements? Isn't `x` the element you want to use for splitting?

Comment: Sorry, I had badly mistyped the text (Friday, written in a rush, before end of work week), now it should be clear, I want a tree like the initial one with one `<x>` per each duplicate (of the initial tree).

Comment: Why is `<e attr2 = 'foo2' />` missing from the first tree in your output?

Comment: Cause I'm stupid and today dyslectic too, apparently, sorry :-( Now it should be as I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to split the entire tree rooted at `<a>` into two (or more)
>   trees, having the same structure, but only one `<x>` per duplicate

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="//x">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*">
                <xsl:with-param name="x-id" select="generate-id()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>   

<!-- modified identity tranform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:param name="x-id" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="x-id" select="$x-id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x">
    <xsl:param name="x-id" />
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = $x-id">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <a>
      <b attr="foo">
         <d>text</d>
         <x attr1="foo1">x-text-1</x>
         <e attr2="foo2"/>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b attr="foo">
         <d>text</d>
         <x>x-text-2</x>
         <e attr2="foo2"/>
      </b>
   </a>
</root>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!